# The argument type 'List<Plants>?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<Plants>'

Tags: json, flutter, dart, parsing

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
    body: FutureBuilder<List<Plants>>(
      future: PlantsApi.getPlantsLocally(context),
      builder:(context, snapshot) {
        final users = snapshot.data;
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          default:
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Center(child: Text('Some error'),);
          }
          else {
            return buildPlants(users);
          }
        }
      }, 
    ),
  );
```

I'm having error with this one. the users is the error

when I change the `buildPlants(users)` to `buildPlants(users!)` I get this error:

```
 Error: Member not found: 'fromJson'.
    return body.map<Plants>(Plants.fromJson).toList();
                                   ^^^^^^^^
```

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:oplantapp/model/plantData.dart';

class PlantsApi {
  static Future<List<Plants>> getPlantsLocally(BuildContext context) async {
    final assetBundle = DefaultAssetBundle.of(context);
    final data = await assetBundle.loadString('assets/plants.json');
    final body = json.decode(data);

    return body.map<Plants>(Plants.fromJson).toList();
  }
}
```

here is my fetch data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you didn't implement `Plants.fromJson` method in your **Plants** class. Refer [official documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/json#serializing-json-inside-model-classes)

```
...
Plants.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : name = json['name'],
        email = json['email'];
...
```

After implementing `Plants.fromJson` method in **Plants**. Try to change your return statement

```
return body.map<Plants>((e) => Plants.fromJson(e)).toList();
```

Comment: thank you the error of  Error: Member not found: 'fromJson'.
    return body.map<Plants>(Plants.fromJson).toList();
                                   ^^^^^^^^ is fixed. thank you.